# Possible to specify different text size in CSS for iPad devices?

Tags: css, ipad

I am wanting the text from some of my `HTML` pages to be bigger on iPad devices and I was wondering is this possible? In particular I'd like to change the `h3` text size and paragraph text size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  
{ 
    h3 { text-size:/*amount of value you want to set*/ }
}
```

Using media query will help you make it. It's CSS3 feature, so it may not be compatible with old browsers.

If the target device is with retina, then declare this in your css.

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
{ 
    h3 { text-size:/*amount of value you want to set*/ }
}
```

And if you want to change the style according to landspace or portrait mode on Ipad,
then add this query.

```
 @media only screen 
 and (min-device-width : 768px) 
 and (max-device-width : 1024px)
 and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
 and (orientation : landscape) // add this. value options "landspace / portrait"
 { 
     h3 { text-size:/*amount of value you want to set*/ }
 }
```

Comment: Good answer, just wanted to point out that the first media query will target **all** browsers who's width is between 768 and 1024, including desktops, other tablets, etc.

Comment: Thanks. So if an iPad device is loading the content, does all the other code outside of media only screen get ignored? Or does it still get executed, unless the code in media only screen overrides it?

Comment: @CoDEFRo  Yes you right, the loaded CSSs will be executed. Media query just overrides the existing css attributes ( if there's the same css declarations on elements ), when it finds the target device.

Answer (score 1):

This guy here did a great job setting media queries for iPads and made a list, you might want to check it out:

http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/